# HA in k8s cluster in case of node failure pointed by A record of domain

Tags: domain, kubernetes, high-availability

I've got a question of "what if" kind

Suppose there is a Kubernetes cluster with 4 nodes and some domain which points to IP of node no 1 and web app using this domain having 1 pod per node. If node 1 will fail then in the current state of my knowledge the app will fail cause A record is pointing to that node which is broken

How it can be solved to maintain HA environment?

Answer (score 1):

That is the problem that a [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/) is designed to solve, and if you are in a cloud environment (or otherwise have an operator that will provision something that *looks* like a load balancer), then `type: LoadBalancer` will provision a stable entrypoint from outside the cluster to inside the cluster, and then kubernetes will route around that Node failure.

Under the covers, `type: LoadBalancer` is just glue between `type: NodePort` and the load balancer, so even if you don't have a formal load balancer mechanism available to you, using `type: NodePort` and a copy of haproxy pointed at **every** Node in your cluster will go a long way toward addressing your risk

Comment: So load balancer will be single point of failure in this case too right? in case of it being offline someone will have to change A record to mitigate this failure? or maybe there is an option to make it automatically like "in case of failure node/LB1 point domain to node/LB2"

also thank you for answer :)

Comment: Heh, it's turtles all the way down! But seriously, there is _always_ going to be a point of failure but without knowing more about your environment, and the ways you would drive down such a risk _outside_ of kubernetes, it's hard to offer concrete advice for how to drive down the risk _with_ kubernetes. I know that some "bare metal" folks use IPVS+haproxy, others have fancy networking gear that solves the same problem, and others do literally use haproxy just with DNS R-R across the haproxy machines. But to come all the way back to your original question, no, publishing Node IPs is always bad

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mdaniel for clarification!

I've also found useful links to dive deeper

[Is it possible to make redundancy on HAProxy server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/238605/is-it-possible-to-make-redundancy-on-haproxy-server)

[How to setup HAProxy with failover?](https://serverfault.com/questions/281230/how-to-setup-haproxy-with-failover)

It's also a good idea to check out topics such as floating ip, keepalived, and if your vendor have api for changing destination of floating ip here on digitalocean you can check how-to
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-highly-available-haproxy-servers-with-keepalived-and-floating-ips-on-ubuntu-14-04